# All distinct values of m:n relationship

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble finding a clean solution for this problem.

If we have some products:

```
id          name        price       store
----------------------------------------------
1           product1    10.30       inmyzone.com
2           product2    47          googol.su
3           product3    .99         Nederlandse Winkel
4           product4    321,09      Nederlandse Winkel
```

And some properties:

```
id          name
----------------------------------------------
1           brand
2           color
```

These values are related like this:

```
product_id  property_id value
----------------------------------------------
1           1           Great Stuff
2           1           Best Brand Name Ever
3           1           Great Stuff
4           1           So bad, it's good
1           2           Red
2           2           Blue
3           2           Blue
```

How can I for example find all prices, brands, stores and colors if

- `store` = 'Nederlandse Winkel'
- `color` = 'blue' AND `store` = 'Nederlandse Winkel'
- `price` >= 10 AND `price` <= 10

**What I've been doing up until now.**

If I want all colors and stores if `brand` = 'Great Stuff'.

1 JOIN the tables to a complete product table and with WHERE (actually HAVING, since it was programmatically easier) I excluded all unnecessary data.

```
id          name        price       store               brand                 color
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           product1    10.30       inmyzone.com        Great Stuff           red
3           product3    .99         Nederlandse Winkel  Great Stuff           blue
```

2 I execute this query:

```
SELECT "color" AS filter_name, 'color' AS filter_value 
FROM ({product table of step 1}) AS products 
GROUP BY filter_value
UNION ALL
SELECT "store" AS filter_name, 'store' AS filter_value 
FROM ({product table of step 1}) AS products 
GROUP BY filter_value
```

The problem with this approach is that I have to recreate the product table of step on 1 for every filter. Is there an alternative?

Thank you

**UPDATE: This is what the result would be**

```
color     blue
color     red
store     inmyzone.com
store     Nederlandse Winkel
```

The way it's outputted isn't important as long as it contains all possible options.

Comment: Can you add an example of what you expect as output?

Comment: Perhaps use an association table to replace the m:n relationship with two 1:m relationships. This would simplify things.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen The way it's outputted is not important, as long as I can tell that the colors 'red' and 'blue' are available and stores 'inmyzone.com' and 'Nederlandse Winkel'.

Comment: @NeutralHandle: 1:m is not possible, since not all products have a color and some products have completely different properties.

Comment: @jmrc I mean just use a table containing productId and propertyId, each foreign keys to the other tables. Its a standard approach for simplifying m:n relationships: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table

Comment: @NeutralHandle: That's what I did, isn't it? But the problem is that the product table of step 1 has to recreated for every value as shown in step 2. That's why I'm looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select pv.product_id
from (<your step1 query here>) pv
group by pv.product_id
```

And then adding a `having` clause such as:

```
having sum(store = 'Nederlandse Winkel') > 0
having sum(store = 'Nederlandse Winkel') > 0 and sum(color = 'blue') > 0
```

I don't understand the third condition.